# SailsJS jQuery not working in views

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sails.js

Currently i am working with SailsJS v0.10 and i can't make my javascript work in the views of my app. I can only make my script work within the layout.ejs but if i move my script to other location (like users/add) the script did not work anymore.

Sample of my code...

`<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>`

my js code at /views/users/add.ejs

`<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('hey');
</script>`

[see also this codes](http://pastebin.com/dntfa2Za)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you forgot to initiate your angular app...

`<html ng-app="windowExample">`

Answer (score 2):

The path to your script is relative to the `assets` folder, so you can use something like:

```
<script src="js/foo.js"></script>
<script src="js/user/bar.js"></script>
```

Comment: put a forward slash before that. <script src="/js/foo.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `/` before the assets might work. Like this... `<script src="/assets/js/something.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned make sure your linking to your script file like this (the assets directory is your root).

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

If you have done this, please edit your question to reflect this.

2nd, open your developer tools and check your console log. Have this open as your page loads. Report errors here and report what errors are listed.